# map jj to Esc in inputrc (readline)

Tags: bash, vim, vi, zsh, readline

How can I map <kbd>jj</kbd> to <kbd>Esc</kbd> in inputrc so it gets picked up by apps using GNU Readline (python, mongoshell, ...)

all works fine on zsh using:

```
bindkey -M viins 'jj' vi-cmd-mode
```

this is my current inputrc:

```
set editing-mode vi
set keymap vi

# turn off the stupid bell
set bell-style none
$if mode=vi
    set keymap vi-command
    "gg": beginning-of-history
    "G": end-of-history
    #"jj": vi-movement-mode
    set keymap vi-insert
    "\C-w": backward-kill-word
    "\C-p": history-search-backward
$endif
```

Comment: thanks for the zsh line, it got me started on setting up a vim/emacs hybrid readline

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You should rearrange the inputrc so the commented line comes after `set keymap vi-insert`.

Like this:

```
set bell-style none
$if mode=vi
    set keymap vi-command
    "gg": beginning-of-history
    "G": end-of-history
    set keymap vi-insert       #notice how the "jj" movement is
    "jj": vi-movement-mode     #after 'set keymap vi-insert'?
    "\C-w": backward-kill-word
    "\C-p": history-search-backward
$endif
```

Comment: To show what applies to insert mode and what applies to command mode, refer to this answer: http://superuser.com/questions/286781/readline-difference-between-vi-vi-move-vi-command-vi-insert-keymaps

Comment: Is it possible to do something like this for <C-c>?  I'm used to using that in vim and it would be nice to have it exit insert mode rather than going to the next line.  Preferably without changing control-c functionality when a process is running. (I'm currently using bash btw)

Comment: @mrfred inputrc is for libreadline enabled applications and to a lesser set of libncurses applications. Bash uses libreadline but vim uses its own processor. For vim try looking at `:help map` while in vim, or `$ vim +':help map' from shell.