# vim 'imap' functionality in bash

Tags: bash, vim, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a way to emulate Vim's 'imap' functionality in bash?

For example, in Vim I use `imap jj <ESC>` and `imap kk <TAB>` as convenience shortcuts.  For those who don't use Vim, it means that when you type jj in short succession, it would be the equivalent of hitting escape.

The benefit is two very commonly used keystrokes easily accessible from the home row.

I realize there's a way in bash to bind existing keys, or combinations of keys to something else... but is there a way to bind sequences of keys pressed separately?

Comment: Is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6839006/map-jj-to-esc-in-inputrc-readline an answer to your question? ("readline" is the library bash uses to handle keyboard interaction).

Comment: Have a look at the bash `man` page (`man bash`), around line 1755 or so, search for `inputrc`.   You probably could set up keys as you wish.  (Of course, __bookkeeper__ is going to be hard to type in bash though)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Awesome, thanks.  Using the inputrc in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6839006/map-jj-to-esc-in-inputrc-readline plus adding "kk": "\t" to the keymap for vi-insert worked great.

Comment: @user3799553, glad to hear that helped; I've tried to extract the relevant part as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the file `~/.inputrc` to configure the readline library, which bash uses for handling input.

Consider something akin to the following:

```
$if mode=vi
    set keymap vi-insert
    "kk": "\t"
$endif
```

See [map jj to Esc in inputrc (readline)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6839006/map-jj-to-esc-in-inputrc-readline) for a more complete example.

Comment: Note, instead of '"\t"' using 'complete' is better.