# How to set VIM key binding in ZSH/terminal

Tags: vim, zsh

In my normal use of Vim I have a key binding ("jj") to enter `NORMAL` mode. I accomplish this by setting a mapping configuration in `~/.vimrc` -> `:imap jk <Esc>`. However this binding does not take effect in ZSH on Mac OS Terminal. Is there a way to enable this?

*Edit/Update: I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6839006/map-jj-to-esc-in-inputrc-readline) which appears to sort of indirectly answer my question within its question to something else (not its answer). Leaving this open as that original thread does not directly answer the question*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [map jj to Esc in inputrc (readline)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6839006/map-jj-to-esc-in-inputrc-readline)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ZSH and Vim are configured separately, in `~/.zshrc` and `~/.vimrc` respectively. You can add the `jj` key binding to your zsh terminal by adding the following line to you ~/.zshrc file.

```
# Add "jj" shortcut to enter NORMAL mode
bindkey -M viins 'jj' vi-cmd-mode
```